# Expand circle animation from top left corner of the screen

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm trying to make an expanding circle animation from top left corner of the screen to the entire screen.

I got it working as expected but from page center:

```css
@keyframes anim {
 0% { clip-path: circle(0% at 50% 50%); }
 100% { clip-path: circle(150%); }
}

#backdrop {
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  z-index: 10;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="backdrop"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your keyframes as below. You are starting your circle from `50% 50%` which is center of the page.

```
0% {
clip-path: circle(0% at 0% 0%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.full {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
    animation-name: anim;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


@keyframes anim {
    0% {clip-path: circle(0% at 150% 0%);}
    100% {clip-path: circle(150%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="full"></div>
```

Comment: Add a small description about the code you provided